# Upgrading to Durandal 2.0 from 1.2 - shell.html not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, durandal

i'm getting a 404 error when trying to activate my shell. it seems to find shell.js but then indicates that it can't find shell.html because it's looking in the wrong place!

i tried forcing the convention to expressly tell it where to look, but it's still not working. like so: `viewLocator.useConvention('viewmodels', 'views', '');`

but i still get:

`App/viewmodels/shell.html 404 (Not Found)`

Obviously it shouldn't be looking in `app/viewmodels/`, it should look in `app/views/`

the difference in my project is that i'm not using the '/scripts/' folder for 3rd party stuff, i am using my own folder called '/content/'. i'm also putting almost everything that has to do with durandal in the '/app/' folder.

here's the structure of some key files in my project:

```
+app (folder)
  main.js
  > durandal (folder)
     app.js
     r.js
     require.js
     text.js
     viewEngine.js
     viewLocator.js
 > plugins (folder)
     router.js
 > viewmodels (folder)
     shell.js
 > views (folder)
     shell.html
```

in main.js > 
  here's where i set the shell to be called:
`app.setRoot('viewmodels/shell');`

and here's the paths also in main.js:

```
paths: {
        'text': 'durandal/text',
        'durandal': 'durandal',
        'plugins': 'durandal/plugins',
        'transitions': 'durandal/transitions'
}
```

in shell.js >
  well, it doesn't really matter because it's already thrown the 404 by this point.

any ideas?

Comment: The path to `plugins` and `text` doesn't look correct. If the baseUrl is `app` then it should be `'plugins' :  'plugins'` and `'text' :  'text'`.

Comment: good thought, but they're correct. it's a bit unclear from my drawing above, but the path is actually 'app > durandal' and the 'plugins' directory below that. if i remove the 'durandal/' part, it doesn't find the files and throws a 404 error on top of the one i'm already getting.

Answer (score 1):

i see now. i had the wrong path to the defined modules in main.js. not sure why they weren't throwing an error, but anyhow, here's what i changed:

from:
    `define(['../app/durandal/system', '../app/durandal/app', '../app/durandal/viewLocator'], function (system, app, viewLocator) {`

to:
    `define(['durandal/system', 'durandal/app', 'durandal/viewLocator'], function (system, app, viewLocator) {`

seems to work now.